# Is it possible to have 2 JPanels in a Border layout at the same location?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm writing a game which uses a border layout with a JPanel using BorderLayout.CENTER.   What I'd like to be able to do is sometimes hide this panel and replace it with another panel with different information.  I added both to the container and set visibility of one of them to false.

Then later I try:

```
panel1.setVisible(false);
panel2.setVisible(true);
```

but this doesn't display the new panel. I just see gray.   Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a nested JPanel with a [CardLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for that.